# Programatically create node + panel configuration?

Tags: 7, panels

Is there a way to programmatically create a panel node with a certain layout?

Comment: I'm sure there _is_ a way. However, you should drop Panels Nodes and use [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) instead. PN is essentially deprecated.

Comment: So does that mean rather then going to the "Panel Content" area I can now just go to the "Edit" area? Is that what Panelizer does?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question, possibly because I don't use PN. Also it seems like a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

For some people, Panel Nodes is good enough. Depends on your circumstances.

The below will create a panel node with 2 column bricks layout and will use the In Place Editor (IPE):

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->title = t('Home');
$node->type = 'panel';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->status = 1;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->comment = 0;

$node->panels_node = array(
    'layout' => 'twocol_bricks',
    'css_id' => NULL,
    'pipeline' => 'ipe', // change this to "standard" if you don't want to use the In Place Editor (ipe)
);

// node_submit() populates the node with author UID and creation date
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, it is better to use [Panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer) rather than Panel Nodes.

Here is the code example how to a new display and attach it into panelized node:

```
  $node = is_numeric($node) ? node_load($node) : $node;
  $display = !empty($node->panelizer) ? $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display : FALSE;
  if ($display && !is_numeric($display->did)) {
    $new_display = panels_save_display($display);
    $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display = &$new_display;
    $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE;
    node_save($node);
    // $new_did = $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display->did;
    ctools_include('object-cache');
    ctools_object_cache_clear('panels_node_display_cache', $node->nid);
  }
```

where display should be created only once and re-used when possible.

Here is example how to attach such display into the existing node:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$display = $node->panelizer['page_manager']->display;
$did = is_numeric($display->did) ? $display->did : NULL;
$display = panels_load_display($did);
$panes = $display->content; // Get this display's panes.

// Attach our new panel.
$uuid = ctools_uuid_generate();
$new_pane = panels_new_pane('node', 'my_node', TRUE);
$new_pane->uuid = $uuid;
$new_pane->pid = "new-" . $uuid;
$new_pane->panel = $region;
$new_pane->shown = 1;
$new_pane->configuration['nid'] = $nid;
$new_pane->configuration['build_mode'] = 'full';
$new_pane->configuration['link_node_title'] = FALSE;
$new_pane->configuration['links'] = FALSE;
$new_pane->configuration = array_merge($new_pane->configuration, $opts);
$display->panels[$region][] = $new_pane->pid;
$display->content[$new_pane->pid] = $new_pane;
$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display = $display;
$node->panelizer['page_manager']->display_is_modified = TRUE;
$result = node_save($node);
// Clear ctools caches.
ctools_include('object-cache');
ctools_object_cache_clear('panels_node_display_cache', $pnid);
```